# WSO2is SCIM auth user

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2 Identity Server with PostgreSQL, i work in node and i already use  a SCIM 2.0 api for create new users, my question is, how i use SCIM to create a authentication user for my app, in my app how i know when the user have  a valid token.

to create a new user i use this:

```
curl -v -k --user user:pass --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"nae","givenName":"name",},"userName":"newuser","password":"newpassword","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"data","type":"home"},{"value":"data","type":"work"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a valid token for the user you have to invoke oAuth flow.

- Create SP in the IS with oAuth configurations.
- Use the client id and secret to get the access token using the created user credentials.

`curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client id:client secret value>" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token`

Refer : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Resource+Owner+Password+Credentials+Grant

Comment: thank you for your answer, i try this solution and works when i create a user from wso2 console, but whe use scim2, i have invalid credentials of user.
Maybe scim2 use another encryption password method of oauth2, or what is the method for create new users if i use oauth2/token for login?

Comment: No, there are no different encryption password. You can use the same password provided in the SCIM user creation

Comment: I can not understand then what happens, when I create a user via scim authentication does not work, if I change the password from the wso2 console, I can authenticate via oath2.

Comment: Can you able to log in to the dashboard using this user (the user must have log in permission to check it). If not send me the error you got in the server.

Comment: I create a new user using scim,  then i try to log in in wso2 console.
I have this in wso2 log:

[2018-11-07 20:05:34,448]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMUserManager} -  User: mynewuser@email.com is created through SCIM.
[2018-11-07 20:06:16,821]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'mynewuser@email.com [-1234]' at [2018-11-07 20:06:16,821-0600]

Comment: Have you assigned the newly created user with a role(with login permission ) to access the console?